# How to refactor Mocha BDD test?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

My solution doesn't work

```
const port = require('../app').port
const superagent = require('superagent')
const expect = require('expect')
const server = require('http').createServer(app)

const boot = () => {
  server.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.info(`Express server listening on port ${app.get('port')}`)
  })
}
```

When I try

```
mocha tests
Express.js server is listening on port 3000

ReferenceError: app is not defined
```

The OP suggested this

```
const server = http.createServer(app)
```

But in that case I got output

```
ReferenceError: http is not defined
```

Folder

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 miki miki   503 апр 14 18:07 app.js
drwxrwxr-x   2 miki miki  4096 апр 14 17:43 db/
drwxrwxr-x 235 miki miki 12288 апр 14 18:43 node_modules/
-rw-rw-r--   1 miki miki   413 апр 14 18:43 package.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 miki miki 91189 апр 14 18:43 package-lock.json
drwxrwxr-x   2 miki miki  4096 апр 14 17:43 public/
drwxrwxr-x   2 miki miki  4096 апр 14 17:43 routes/
drwxrwxr-x   2 miki miki  4096 апр 14 18:16 test-example/
drwxrwxr-x   2 miki miki  4096 апр 14 18:30 tests/
drwxrwxr-x   2 miki miki  4096 апр 14 17:55 views/
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually import the `app`-module in order to be able to use it. Something like this should work:

```
const app = require('../app'); // adjust the path if necessary
const superagent = require('superagent')
const expect = require('expect')
const server = require('http').createServer(app)

const boot = () => {
  server.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.info(`Express server listening on port ${app.get('port')}`)
  })
}
```